# Powershell: Return NIC "Windows Name" instead of "Device Name"

Tags: powershell, wmi

Good afternoon folks.

I have a script that gives a bunch of info about a newly built server. One thing I can't figure out, is how to get it to display the "Windows Name" of the NIC (ex. "VLAN 111" or "Internal Backup vLAN") instead of what shows below in the "Description". What am I missing?

```
        Foreach ($objAdapter in $colAdapters)
    {
        if ($objAdapter.IPEnabled -eq "True")
        {
            $NICCount = $NICCount + 1
            If ($NICCount -gt 1)
            {
                $Report+=  " </TABLE>"
                $Report+=  " <DIV class=Solidfiller></DIV>"
                $Report+=  " <TABLE>"
            }
        $Report+=  " <tr>"
        $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>Description</b></font></th>"
******* $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.Description)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  " </tr>"
        $Report+=  " <tr>"
        $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>Physical address</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.MACaddress)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  " </tr>"
        If ($objAdapter.IPAddress -ne $Null)
        {
            $Report+=  " <tr>"
            $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>IP Address / Subnet Mask</b></font></th>"
            $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$(gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddress } | Foreach-Object { [IPAddress]$_ } | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'Internetwork' } | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddressToString }) / $($objAdapter.IPSubnet)</font></td>"
            $Report+=  " </tr>"
            $Report+=  " </tr>"
            $Report+=  " <tr>"
            $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>Default Gateway</b></font></th>"
            $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway)</font></td>"
            $Report+=  " </tr>"
                }
        $Report+=  " <tr>"
        $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>DHCP enabled</b></font></th>"
        If ($objAdapter.DHCPEnabled -eq "True")
        {
            $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>Yes</font></td>"
        }
        Else
        {
            $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>No</font></td>"
        }
        $Report+=  " </tr>"
        $Report+=  " <tr>"
        $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>DNS Servers</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>"
        If ($objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $Null)
        {
            $Report+=  " $($objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) "
        }
        $Report+=  " </tr>"
        $Report+=  " <tr>"
        $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>Primary WINS Server</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.WINSPrimaryServer)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  " </tr>"
        $Report+=  " <tr>"
        $Report+=  " <th width='25%'><b>Secondary WINS Server</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.WINSSecondaryServer)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  " </tr>"
        $NICCount = $NICCount + 1
        }
    }
```

The delcaration I have set up higher in the script is:

```
    Write-Output "..Network Configuration"
    $NICCount = 0
    $colAdapters = gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

The result gives me this:
Description: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
Physical address: 00:05:9A:3C:7A:00
IP Address / Subnet Mask: 192.168.240.146 192.168.116.1 192.168.153.1 10.20.30.105 / 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.240.1
DHCP enabled: No
DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

I know the line I am need to change is marked with the ***'s, but I just can't figure out what I need to do. If I need to change the whole command declaration I call to something else to get the same result, I am definitely game.

Thanks ahead of time for all the help!

Comment: Where does `$colAdapters` come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen he is using `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` below in his question

Comment: I think what you're looking for is in the win32_networkadapter class...the interfaceindex will (should?) match what you have in the win32_networkadapterconfiguration class.

Comment: @MikeShepard - Win32_NetworkAdapter doesn't give info like DNS, IP, etc. etc. It *does* show what I am looking for under "NetConnectionID" though, so that is where my problem is. I don't know how to combine them both for the info I need.

Comment: @scottwtang has provided an answer which shows a way to combine.

Answer (score 2):

So the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class contains your desired value as the `NetConnectionId` property?

We can save the results of `Win32_NetworkAdapter` with the `InterfaceIndex` value, and compare the `InterfaceIndex` of both `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` and `Win32_NetworkAdapter` to find the correct adapter and get its `NetConnectionId` value.

You add this to your higher up declaration

```
Write-Output "..Network Configuration"
$NICCount = 0
$colAdapters = gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration

#### NEW CODE START ####
########################
# this will save the results of Win32_NetworkAdapter with the InterfaceIndex which will be used to match against, and the NetConnectionId which will replace your table value
$networkAdapters = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select -Property Name, InterfaceIndex, NetConnectionID
##### NEW CODE END #####
########################
```

And add this at the start of your loop

```
foreach ($objAdapter in $colAdapters)
{
    
    #### NEW CODE START ####
    ########################
    # loop through the results of $networkAdapters and compare the InterfaceIndex of Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration against Win32_NetworkAdapter
    # if they match, we save the NetConnectionId as a new property for $objAdapter which can be accessed as $objAdapter.NetConnectionId
    foreach ($adapter in $networkAdapters)
    {    
        if ($objAdapter.InterfaceIndex -eq $adapter.InterfaceIndex)
        {
            $objAdapter | Add-Member -NotePropertyName NetConnectionId -NotePropertyValue $adapter.NetConnectionId
        }
    }
    ##### NEW CODE END #####
    ########################

    if ($objAdapter.IPEnabled -eq "True")
    {

    }    
}
```

And update your starred line

`******* $Report+=  " <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.Description)</font></td>"`

`$objAdapter.Description` should be replaced with `$objAdapter.NetConnectionId`

Comment: Good morning @scottwtang. I tried that, but it didn't change anything. It still showed the old actual adapter name, but when I run the command, 11 shows correct.

Name InterfaceIndex NetConnectionID
Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter 19 
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64 18 Ethernet 4
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM 11 LOCAL PLUG
VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1 23 VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8 7 VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
Citrix Virtual Adapter 9 Citrix Virtual Adapter

Comment: Did you update the starred line in your script as well? I updated my answer to include the changes at the bottom

Comment: I did, but guess I didn't save it when I exited Powershell. I made that change again, and is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you very much!